# Not getting the "Submit for verification" button for OAuth verification in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace-add-ons

I have created a Gmail/Calendar add-on in Google Apps Script and I want to publish it to the marketplace.

I am following the steps at https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/configure-oauth-consent-screen#fill_out_the_oauth_consent_screen. I am on the "Submit for OAuth verification" step which leads to https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#submit-howto. It says:

4. Click the Edit App button.
5. Enter the information required on the configuration page, and then click **Submit for verification**. If the submit for verification button does not appear at the end of the configuration pages, save what you have completed and repeat steps 1-4.

I have gone through all the steps but the **Submit for verification** never comes up. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you do not have a domain name that you own/control. gmail.com and github.com are not owned by you.

[Verify your site ownership](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?ref_topic=3473162#userconsent&zippy=%2Cuser-consent%2Cauthorized-domains)

Your second problem is that you are requesting restricted scopes. Google will probably demand a security audit. Sensitive scopes can also trigger an audit.

To verify, create another client and remove the sensitive and restricted scopes and add a domain name that you own/control. To read more about the effect of scopes and possible exceptions:

[Sensitive and Restricted Scopes](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#sensitive-scopes)

Comment: So I have to host a website somewhere? I've seen many add-ons with links to GitHub.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan You must host your own website and control the domain name. The domain must be verified before you can proceed. Google requires this for security reasons. I provided a link for you, However, based upon my experience you will not get approved because of the scopes you are using unless you qualify for an exemption. Not having your own website guarantees you do not qualify.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!